# Does DOCTYPE have to be in uppercase in HTML5?

Tags: html

Does DOCTYPE have to be in uppercase in HTML5?

The start of an HTML5 document is usually written as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

...but is the lowercase also valid?

```
<!doctype html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, the DOCTYPE is case insensitive.
You can find more info here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype

Answer (score 0):

Unlike earlier versions of HTML, in HTML5 the doctype declaration is case-insensitive. In other words  works as well as . Check here: http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/doctype.htm